# Codeigniter select user email NOT IN another table is taking too long to execute

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

My emails_queue table contains more than 900k records so the query becomes slow to find a record that doesn't exist in that table.
I am using Codeigniter

Here's my query

```
$key = $this->config->item('encryption_key');

        $query = $this->db
            ->select(
                "
                users.id, AES_DECRYPT(users.email, '$key') as email, 
                AES_DECRYPT(users.first_name, '$key') as first_name, 
                AES_DECRYPT(users.state, '$key') as state,
                AES_DECRYPT(users.phone_number, '$key') as phone,
                prescriptions.user_id, prescriptions.expire_date
            "
            )
            ->from('users')
            ->join('prescriptions', 'users.id = prescriptions.user_id', 'LEFT')
            ->where(
                "AES_DECRYPT(users.email, '$key') NOT IN (SELECT to_email FROM emails_queue WHERE template = 'renewal_template')",
                null,
                false
            )
            ->where(
                "users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM prescriptions GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(user_id) > 1)",
                null,
                false
            );
```

How can I make it execute faster?

Answer (score 0):

```
NOT IN ( SELECT ... )
```

is often poorly optimized.  Try to turn it into one of these:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )

LEFT JOIN .. WHERE .. IS NULL
```

(To discuss further, please provide the generated SQL.)